# Accumulate Events from Multiple Topics using Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I do apologise if this is a dumb question.

I have a scenario whereby I have 3 topics from an upstream service (which are not keyed). Unfortunately, I can't change the behaviour of the 3 topics.

The upstream service bulk publishes all the messages at the end of the day, and I need to get an accumulated view of the transactions, since the order of the transactions matters for a downstream service.

I understand I can't re-order the messages in the different partitions of the topics, so I figured if i could accumulate them, and my service could then take the accumulated result and re-order them before processing.

However, I am noticing a weird behaviour, and I am hoping someone can clarify what I am missing.

When I do the operation with 1 to 500 accounts, I see 500 messages accumulated and displayed in the output topic.

However, when I try the same operation with 10,000 accounts, I see more output than there should be. (13,000 messages on output topic).

```java
    KStream<String, TransactionAccumulator> transactions =
        disbursements
            .merge(repayments)
            .merge(fees)
            .groupBy(
                (k, v) -> v.getAccountId(),
                with(
                    String(),
                    serdeFrom(
                        new JsonSerializer<>(mapper),
                        new JsonDeserializer<>(Transaction.class, mapper))))
            .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.MINUTES)))
            .aggregate(
                TransactionAccumulator::new,
                (key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.add(value),
                (aggKey, aggOne, aggTwo) -> aggOne.merge(aggTwo),
                Materialized.with(
                    String(),
                    serdeFrom(
                        new JsonSerializer<>(mapper),
                        new JsonDeserializer<>(TransactionAccumulator.class, mapper))))
            .toStream((key, value) -> key.key());
```

As stated earlier, the upstream service bulk publishes all the events at the end of the day (instead of real-time).

Would appreciate what I am missing here, since for smaller volumes, it seems to work.

---

## Update 1

I tried the suggestion proposed of using [suppression](https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api#window-final-results) to try to only send the final window.

However, when using this, it basically does not publish any messages to the output topic, though I see that there are messages in the "KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE"

The updated code with the suppress is as follows.

```java
   disbursements
        .merge(repayments)
        .merge(fees)
        .groupBy(
            (key, value) -> value.getAccountId(),
            Grouped.with(
                Serdes.String(),
                Serdes.serdeFrom(
                    new JsonSerializer<>(mapper),
                    new JsonDeserializer<>(Transaction.class, mapper))))
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1)).grace(ofMinutes(1)))
        .aggregate(
            TransactionAccumulator::new,
            (key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.add(value),
            Materialized.with(
                Serdes.String(),
                Serdes.serdeFrom(
                    new JsonSerializer<>(mapper),
                    new JsonDeserializer<>(TransactionAccumulator.class, mapper))))
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(BufferConfig.unbounded()))
        .mapValues(
            value -> {
              LOGGER.info(
                  "Sending {} Transactions for {}",
                  value.getTransactions().size(),
                  value.getAccountId());
              return value;
            })
        .toStream((key, value) -> key.key());
```

I also do not see the log messages introduced. For clarity, I am using Spring Cloud Stream in this experiment, and the final log entries I see on the stream-app are as follows.

```
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [StreamConsumer-consume-applicationId-de25a238-5f0f-4d84-9bd2-3e7b01b7f0b3] State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.i.RocksDBTimestampedStore      : Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000006.1583625600000 in regular mode
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.i.RocksDBTimestampedStore      : Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000006.1583625600000 in regular mode
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.i.RocksDBTimestampedStore      : Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000006.1583625600000 in regular mode
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.i.RocksDBTimestampedStore      : Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000006.1583625600000 in regular mode
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.i.RocksDBTimestampedStore      : Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000006.1583625600000 in regular mode
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.i.RocksDBTimestampedStore      : Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000006.1583625600000 in regular mode
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.i.RocksDBTimestampedStore      : Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000006.1583625600000 in regular mode
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.i.RocksDBTimestampedStore      : Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000006.1583625600000 in regular mode
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.i.RocksDBTimestampedStore      : Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000006.1583625600000 in regular mode
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.i.RocksDBTimestampedStore      : Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000006.1583625600000 in regular mode
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.i.RocksDBTimestampedStore      : Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000006.1583625600000 in regular mode
INFO 23436 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.i.RocksDBTimestampedStore      : Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000006.1583625600000 in regular mode
```

Comment: Are there any duplicates in the input source?

Comment: There should not be. I had built a test case to simulate the upstream service.

The simulator starts X number of Account Actors, and then it pretends to be someone with the account and simulates transactions every hour for a month, generating one of the 3 message types.

Each account in the test is `"ACCOUNT-" + actorIndex`. Each generated transaction is unique by the `accountId` and a generated `transactionId` (UUID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I can't comment yet, but here are my two cents:

1. `KGroupedStream.aggregate()`: Kafka Stream uses a [record cache](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#record-caches) to control the rate at which aggregated updates are emitted from Materialized view (or KTable) of `aggregate` to state store and downstream processor. E.g with messages:

```
("word1", 4)
("word1", 2)
("word2", 3)
("word1", 1)
```

And your word count topology:

```
wordCntPerSentenceKStream
    .groupByKey()
    .aggregate(() -> 0, (word, newWordCnt, aggsWordCnt) -> aggsWordCnt + newWordCnt, Materialized.as("word-cnt-store").withValueSerde(Serdes.Integer())
    .toStream();
```

you may received downstream messages like this:

```
("word1", 6)
("word2", 3)
("word1", 7)
```

So my guess is that your input topic may contains multiple transactions for a single AccountId, and record cache get flushed when the cache (`cache.max.bytes.buffering`) is full or `commit.interval.ms` is meeted.

2. If your sink is Idempotent, you can just override your `TransactionAccumulator` with the new message key or you can use `KTable.suppress()` as stated [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-328%3A+Ability+to+suppress+updates+for+KTables) to only emit the last message of the aggregated window.

Comment: You are right.


A single account may have multiple disbursements, fees, and repayments. Within each transaction is a transaction date.


The use case here, is that a repayment must be for the disbursements and fees that occurred before the repayment transaction date.


I tried the suppression as documented at https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api#window-final-results with a 1 minute window and 1 minute grace.


However, when I run the stream, I don't see any data being emitted downstream.


I verify by writing the output of the stream in a DB

Comment: How do you test the `supress`, note that suppress only emit the last message when there is a new messages arrived with greater record timestamp on  a next, different window.
For more intuitive debugging, you can add debug log in aggregate.add(value) or in aggOne.merge(aggTwo), or using a map((k-v) -> {log.debug(v); return v});

Comment: I included the snippet on how I am using suppression.

Also, thanks for your suggestion to use `map` to output log messages


I wonder if what you mentioned regarding the window behavior might be causing the suppression to not work.

As mentioned, the upstream service publishes all the events in bulk at the end of the day, so they aren't really coming in real time, but more as a single large stream of events. Does that mean that the record timestamp is causing the window to not work correctly ?

Comment: Maybe, but I really recommend write a topology test (https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html) for that, or consume from a dummy topic to check the behavior of the topology.

Comment: And if the producer only produce bulk of message at the end of day, may be some last events of a window may still get suppressed, so maybe a workaround is using a `Processor` or a `Transfomer` for your case (read about processor API)  to save to local state directly butn not forward to downstream yet, and if the time is up (using punctuate WALL_CLOCK_TIME) we flush the local state to downstream using context.forward()